# How to extract DATE from DATETIME format? Error Code 1292 MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am trying to separate the date and time from the column starttime, and only keep the date to insert into a new column, starttday.

I've tried `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(starttime, '%Y, %m, %e') AS starttday` and `UPDATE table SET starttday = CAST(starttime AS DATE)` , but I still receiver the same error code 1292.

This is the table I am working with:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `DATE()` fuction.

```
select date('2022-07-07 15:30:10'); -- result 2022-07-07
```

Comment: I've tried this before, still the same error due to the datetime format

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73030364/edit) to show the complete error message, as well as the schema for your table.

Comment: @Crystal Have you tried it in MySQL command-line client? Sometimes Workbench may enforce its own rules depending on its version. Please also execute 'select version();' in command-line and give us feedback.